# Python: Using variable values in regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, expression

I am searching through a string and am returning matches that are at least n characters long and start with "hi" and end with "bye".

Let's say `n = 10` and `str = "himalayashibye"`.

I would like to do:

```
stringFinder = re.findall("hi.{n-5}*bye",str)
```

(I am subtracting 5 from n because hi and bye already make up five out of n characters.)

However, this does not seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: sorry for the duplication and thanks for the reference. This answers my question!

Comment: Even if you get the syntax right this isn't going to return what you want. I believe it would return the entire string instead of the instances of "hi" and "bye". You probably want `re.match`

Answer (score 0):

The string form (which the comment above addresses) is already being used. So continue with it, e.g.:

```
"hi.{%d}*bye" % (n - 5)
```

However note that this still yields something not-quite right and, with `n = 10`, results in:

```
"hi.{5}*bye"
```

This isn't quite right because `.{5}*` means "match groups of 5 (`.{5}`)" 0 or more times (so 0, 5, 10, 15 ..). There are many words not on these boundaries that *won't* match like `hi1234567bye`. This doesn't match because `1234567` is not a multiple of the 5-group.

Instead, consider `.{5,}` which will "match at least 5 times" and only accept words longer than `hi12345bye`.

Comment: I think OP wants at least 5 so it should be `{5,}`

Comment: @Cfreak I agree (after a re-read), edited the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly agree with user2246674, although the original question was "at least n characters long". Therefore `.{5,}` has to be used.

```
>>> import re
>>> n = 10
>>> pat = r"hi.{%d,}bye"%(n-5)
>>> pat
'hi.{5,}bye'
>>> s = "himalayashibye"
>>> re.findall(pat, s)
['himalayashibye']
>>>
```